# Как узнать координаты мышки через javascript или jquery?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!
Пишу один скрипт для меню, но столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Необходимо узнать при событии `hover` на каких координатах стоит мышка?
Как это сделать с помощью `javascript` или `jQuery`?
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('ид_вашего_элемента').onmouseover = function(e) {
  alert('x = ' + e.pageX + '; y = '+e.pageY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот (это работает ВО ВСЕХ БРАУЗЕРАХ в отличие от кода [[@LightShock](/users/7580/lightshock)](/users/7580/lightshock)):

```
function onhover(evt){ 
   evt = window.event ? window.event : evt;
   alert("X: " + evt.clientX);
   alert("Y: " + evt.clientY);
}
obj.onmouseover = onhover; // obj - это ваш обьект
/*
 Например:
 document.getElementById("id вашего элемента").onhover;
*/
```

Comment: clientX|Y дают координаты мыши без учета скроллинга. pageX|Y с учетом. См. [здесь][1].

Кроме того, почему onmouseover? onmousemove же!

[1]:http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1869-jQuery-Mouse-Events-PageX-Y-vs-ClientX-Y.htm